# Magento get all customers who are not unsubscribed

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get a list of all customers who are not unsubscribed. That is I don't want those customers who have unsubscribed themselves after subscribing. I can get list of customer like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
->addAttributeToSelect('email');
```

What should I apply on this $collection to filter out unsubscribed customers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$collectionSub = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('email')
->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_status'.  array('eq' => 0)) // 0 not subscribed
->load();
$array = array();
foreach($collectionSub as $sub) {
 $array[] = $sub['subscriber_email'];
}
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
->addAttributeToSelect('email')
->addFieldToFilter('email', array('in', $array);
```

Read [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento).

Comment: Thanks Knase, but I also want customers who have not subscribed. Sort of 'not in' with collectionSub containing unsubscribed customers, I'll give a try for the above.

Comment: Ok. Change 1 to 0 in code with eq. addFieldToFilter('subscriber_status'. array('eq' => 0))

Comment: I'm getting this error when executing the above code:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Newsletter_Model_Resource_Subscriber::getCollection()

Comment: I wrote getResourceModel but will be getModel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this:

```
$array = array();

$collectionSub = Mage::getResourceModel ('newsletter/subscriber_collection')           
        -> AddFieldToFilter ('subscriber_status', array ('eq' => 3));  // unsubscribed


foreach($collectionSub as $sub) {
    $array[] = $sub['subscriber_email'];
}

$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addFieldToFilter('email', array('nin', $array));     // all others that have not unsubscribed
```